# get unique product from connectiontable with stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where i want to grab some data through a connection table. The database is old and have no constraint.

This is my procedure:

```
    select distinct(p.id), pd.language, p.Company, pd.shortDescription from dbo.Category c
    join dbo.ProductCategory pc on c.id = pc.CategoryId
    join dbo.Product p on pc.id = p.id
    join dbo.ProductDescription pd on p.id = pd.id
where
    c.Company = 'Normstahl' and 
    c.languageid = 'en' and 
    p.Company = 'Normstahl' and 
    pc.Company = 'Normstahl' and
    c.id != 'Deckenlauf' and 
    pd.language = 'en' and
    pd.Company = 'Normstahl'
```

and as you can see i want to select products that is not connected to the category 'Deckenlauf'.

the problem is that if a product is connected to multiple categories i will recive the product that is connected to that category anyway since it just skips the product that is connected to the category but finds the same product that is connected to another category.

```
 id CategoryId  Company
  1 Deckenlauf  Normstahl
  1 RGD_EUR9_DL Normstahl
```

this is from the connectiontable between category and product. So in my stored procedure i don't want to recieve any products with the id = 1 but now i will because if takes the second row since it is not connected to the category 'Deckenlauf'. How can i solve this problem in my stored procedure?

Comment: Which is it, [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server]?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
 select distinct(p.id), pd.language, p.Company, pd.shortDescription from dbo.Category c
    join dbo.ProductCategory pc on c.id = pc.CategoryId
    join dbo.Product p on pc.id = p.id
    join dbo.ProductDescription pd on p.id = pd.id
where
    c.Company = @companyName and 
    c.languageid = @languageId and 
    p.Company = @companyName and 
    pc.Company = @companyName and
    c.id != @categoryId and 
    pd.language = @languageId and
    pd.Company = @companyName and
    p.id not in (select id from ProductCategory where CategoryId = @categoryId)
```

by adding the last select

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a LEFT JOIN with a condition/filter and WHERE IS NULL to check whether the product has any links to the chosen category.

While your subselect solution most definately would work and maybe be more readable the it should give you better performance.

Assuming I've understood how you use your input parameters to the stored procedure it would be something like this:

```
 LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductCategory pc on pc.id = p.id AND pc.CategoryId = @categoryId -- Only join for the chosen category
 WHERE pc.CategoryId IS NULL and -- Only include rows which did not "hit" the left join
```

I've updated your solution and also moved what seemed to me to be join conditions, i.e. the pd.Company and pc.Company to the ON part.

In addition I've removed the join to Category as you don't seem to use it in the select.

Which gives the following query:

```
 select distinct(p.id), pd.language, p.Company, pd.shortDescription 
 from  dbo.Product p 
    left join dbo.ProductDescription pd on p.id = pd.id AND pd.Company = p.Company AND pd.languageid = @languageId
    left join dbo.ProductCategory pc on pc.id = p.id AND pc.Company = p.Company AND pc.CategoryId = @categoryId 
  where pc.CategoryId IS NULL -- No matching category exists
    and p.Company = @companyName
```

Note that the left join to ProductDescription is there to include rows in the result even for products that do not have a description for the supplied @languageid, as this is how the query in your solution would work.
This could/should be changed to an inner join if products should only be included in the result if they do have a description.